# Edge of convergence radius behaviour

Tags: complex-analysis

what do i have to do if the excercise is "examine the behaviour at the edge of the convergence radius".

I don't even know if that's the correct translation, please fix if not.

For my actual excercise: i have the radius determined at $|z|<e$.
Doesn't that mean already that the behaviour at $|z|=e$ is divergent??

Comment: Yes if the radius is stricly less than $e$ then it diverges at $e$.  Probably they mean it converges for all $|z|<e$ and diverges for $|z|>e$, which means the radius equals $e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sum a_nz^n$ has radius of convergence $R$. Then the series converges for $|z|<R$ and diverges for $|z|>R$, but for $|z|=R$ more or less anything can happen: It can converge everywhere on the circle $|z|=R$ or diverge everywhere on that circle, or converge at some points and diverge at other points.

So if you were asked to "examine the convergence at the boundary" or some such that means they want you to determine for which points with $|z|=R$ the series converges and for which points it diverges.

A few examples with $R=1$:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n/n^2$ converges at every boundary point.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n$ diverges at every boundary point.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n/n$ diverges for $z=1$ but converges for every $z\ne1$ with $|z|=1$.